# Id not properly defined, syntax error GraphQL-Nerdgraph error

Tags: graphql

Trying to execute the below Nerdgraph query, result is showing error. PFB. Need assistance.

```
{
  actor {
    account(id: 123) {
      historicalDataExport {
        export {
          account {
            id: 123
          }
        }
      }
      name
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Response:-

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "column": 9,
          "line": 5
        }
      ],
      "message": "In argument \"id\": Expected type \"ID!\", found null."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your schema ?

Comment: Do you know which specific field that error matches?  Do you mean the innermost `id: 123` to be an [argument](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments) to `account`, rather than a field selector?

Comment: Error matches to 'export' argument. Updated the question.

Comment: You have a syntax error. You either wanted to pass the id in "account(id: 123) {id}" or just have  "account {id}"

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a query variable - it shouldn't be included in the output.

```
{
  actor {
    account(id: 123) {
      historicalDataExport {
        export {
          account {
            id  << by itself, nothing more on this line
          }
        }
      }
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Another example here, it requires id in front of export, this is supposed to be UUID, not sure what to supply here.
{
  actor {
    account(id: 123) {
      historicalDataExport {
        export(id: "") {
          account {
            id
          }
        }
      }
      name
    }
  }
}